# The correct way to update the fields of an @Entity that depend on other entities' state

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, persistence

We ran across a problem where we have to maintain a date field - and preferably persist its value - where the date field is dependent on other entities' state. What is the correct way to address this problem with JPA2 + Hibernate + Spring?

Basically, we have three entities, let's call them `Parent`, `Child`, and `Conf`. The `dependentDate` is calculated by complex business rules that depend on other entities' state. Specifically, it should be `Parent#date` minus `Conf#delay` skipping all days that are weekends or holidays (persistent data).

The problem is that whenever the `Parent#date` changes, all the children's `dependentDate`s should be recalculated. This should happen also whenever the `Child` object's `conf` is changed. Currently, there is a service method for calculating the new date based on the `Child` object's relations (let's call it `calculateDate()`).

We are faced with the problem of where the field's value should be calculated. I came up with three possible solutions. Which of these - or possibly something else - is the preferred way of updating entities' fields that depend on other entities' state?

1. A JPA `EntityListener`

   - this is discouraged in the JPA2 spec, since the EntityListeners should not access other entities
   - the field would always be correct
2. An Spring AOP aspect that updates

   - the logic is hidden in some other class and is not easily seen
   - a risk that the pointcut does not catch all persist/update events
3. Every developer for himself

   - always, when updating an instance of either Parent or Child class, the developer must remember to call the service's `calculateDate()` method
   - should this be in dao or service layer?
   - risk of the developer forgetting to add the call, resulting in erroneous state

The following example shows the entity relations with omitted annotation configuration.

**The entities**

```
public class Parent {
     LocalDate date;
     Set<Child> children;     // one-to-many
}

public class Conf {
     int delay;
}

public class Child {
     LocalDate dependentDate;
     Conf conf;               // many-to-one
     Parent parent;           // many-to-one
}
```

Comment: This is not supposed to be an answer but more an "option 4.": You could add a trigger in the database that updates the date field on updating other tables. This would of course only work if a) your dbms supports triggers, b) you are willing to move business logic out of your main software and c) your entities are "stateless" (like in a spring mvc setup).

Comment: @realsim what do you mean by "stateless" entities? As I see it, the entities are just an state (disclaimer, I do know JPA but not Spring)

Comment: I mean that after the hibernate session is commited, it won't be used again (because of the trigger the entitites are not in the state the session thinks they are). If the session would be reused, it would end with a StaleObjectStateException. But if the session is closed because the request/response is finished and another session would be created on next request that approach would be fine. - I don't like moving business logic out of code myself but sometimes triggers are necessary...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complex business rules that depend on several entities' state belong to the service layer. There shouldn't be so many places in the application where the parent's date and the child's conf are changed, so you shouldn't have so many places where the new date calculation must be done.

If you really have so many places where this is done, you could make it clear that the date must be recomputed by passing a ChildDateUpdater instance (ChildDateUpdater being an interface) to the setter of the parent date and the setter of the child conf. This would make it obvious that something must be done every time these two fields are changed:

In Parent:

```
public void setDate(Date date, ChildDateUpdater childDateUpdater) {
    this.date = date;
    for (Child child : children) {
        childDateUpdater.updateChildDate(child);
    }
}
```

In Child:

```
public void setConf(Conf conf, ChildDateUpdater childDateUpdater) {
    this.conf = conf;
    childDateUpdater.updateChildDate(this);
}
```

Comment: We ended up creating the interface in our `model` package and a corresponding implementation in the service layer. The setter for the dependent field was left public, but the setters for `Conf` and `Parent`'s date are supplied with the updater interface.

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulate your data access in a DAO. When a `Parent` is going to be saved, check if there has been any changes to its values and, if so, update the children accordingly.

The trigger option of `realsim` is also feasible (basically it is the same idea implemented at a different level) but then you would lose portability (and also there will be the issue with instances of Children already loaded not being updated).

Comment: With JPA/Hibernate, a DAO is typically used to retrieve data from the database. This data is returned in the form of entities, which can be changed and whose state is automatically persisted to the database. A typical JPA application doesn't call any DAO.save() method to modify the database.

Comment: @JBNizet Ok I see, I am more used to EJB's flavour of JPA.

Comment: The EJB's flavour is the same as the one I described. JPA entities are attached to a persistence context, linked to the transaction, and when the transaction commits, all the attached entities state is flushed to the database automatically.

Comment: @JBNizet working with JSF and EJB, the fact that the JPA session is not kept open between requests "forced" me to organize my main logic in the JSF controller, with the EJBs only as DAOs (and most simple logic). Maybe I am wrong, could you point me to a good example of design that is in the net?